# radio button in php

Tags: php

I retrieved the value from database and I want to print it in radio button as given below.

```
<input type="radio" value="<?php $row['Username']; ?>" name="myradiobutton" />
```

While storing the 'Username' in the attribute - "value",  it's not working.  Can any one please clarify my doubt.

Comment: if shorthand php  is active then u can try with `<?=$row['username']?>;` but it's is bad practice

Comment: @diEcho Some say it is a bad practice, but if you use PHP for templating, it is quite handy.

Comment: This question explores the controversy of short open tags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Answer (score 4):

You need to output the value with `echo`.  Also escape it with `htmlentities()` as suggested in Fabio M's  comment.

```
<input type="radio" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['Username'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" name="myradiobutton" />
                                ^^^^^^
```

Comment: It's better to escape it using `htmlentities($row['Username'], ENT_QUOTES)`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `echo`:

`value="<?php echo $row['Username']; ?>"`

Answer (score 1):

For the ones that want to know there is also a short tag for this:

```
<input type="radio" value="<?=$row['Username']?>" name="myradiobutton" />
```

Comment: Ususal warnings about `short_open_tags` apply. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: of course but short open tags are on by default now so slowly it is disappearing.